# How to customize/override strapi component

Tags: node.js, reactjs, strapi

Is there some way to customize/override not containers but components in Strapi? In the [customization docs](https://strapi.io/documentation/3.0.0-beta.x/guides/custom-admin.html) is only way to customize containers. For example i want to customize left panel and i can't do it, build failed after that because of import paths. Is it possible?

UPD. Answer: **yes**. But you have to **override or copy connected components** to the folder `/admin/src/components`.

For example if you want to override `LeftMenuLinkContainer`, you need to at least copy `LeftMenuFooter`, `LeftMenuHeader`, `LeftMenuLink`, `LeftMenuLinkSection` with all of contents of overriden `LeftMenuLinkContainer` to the folder above, **of course with import paths resolved**.